# Issue in passing dynamic values in Morris bar chart

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I am using morris bar chart in my page. While sending data statically its working fine. But when I am getting dynamic data in the same format, Bar chart show datas as undefined.

```
                var feedback=data[0].feedback;
                console.log(feedback.length);
                for(i=0;i<feedback.length;i++)
                {
                    customer.push("{ 'x':'"+feedback[i].product_name+"', 'y':"+feedback[i].cust_feedback+"}");
                }
                var customer1=JSON.stringify(customer); 
                customer1 = customer1.replace(/\"/g,'');
                 customer1 = customer1.replace(/\'/g,'"');  
                Morris.Bar({
                              element: 'morris-bar-customer_feedback',
                              data:customer1,
                  xkey: 'x',
                  ykeys: ['y'],
                  labels: ['Tickets'],
                  xLabelAngle: 25
                            });
```

The final array is

```
[{ "x":"TV", "y":1},{ "x":"Laptop", "y":4},{ "x":"Refrigerator", "y":3}]
```

[image: Dynmic Value image]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ! I got the answer.

```
var customer1 = JSON.stringify(customer);   
customer1 = customer1.replace(/\"/g,'');
customer1 = customer1.replace(/\'/g,'"');

var customera = customer1.concat();
var customers = JSON.parse(customera);

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-customer_feedback',
    data:customers,
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y'],
    labels: ['Tickets'],
    xLabelAngle: 25
});
```

I used concat function function and then parsed the Json data. Now I am getting perfect bar chart. I think some unknown data in previous array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that you are passing the `string` instead of javascript object to `data:` option of bar plugin. Can you please try with below modifications:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'morris-bar-customer_feedback',
    data: jQuery.parseJSON(customer1),
    xkey: 'x',
    ykeys: ['y'],
    labels: ['Tickets'],
    xLabelAngle: 25
});
```

Comment: oh yes...i saw you have posted the answer too..!